# What is the shortest formula in excel to covert text date format e.g. 17 Jan, 2023 into regular date format like 1/17/2023?

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I have sales data where transaction date is mentioned as text like 17 Jan,2023. I want to extract month name using TEXT(A1,"MMM") or MONTH(A1) function however these two functions does not work with text date format.

I have tried multiple formulas to convert text date format to normal date format but I didn't get the right answer or the optimized small function or formula.

Later, I tried the following formula but it is too long and complex to use.
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MATCH(MID(A1,1,3),{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"},0)-1+1,DAY(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)))

My question is that if anybody knows are shortest way to do the same?

Comment: `=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "))`

Comment: @SpectralInstance put that as an answer, with a bit of explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

In an English-language locale, the `VALUE()` function will recognise `17 Jan 2023` as a valid date (although you will have to render the date *format* manually), so the `SUBSTITUTE()` function can be used to remove the `,` that appear in your text, and then nesting this in the `VALUE()` function should return an Excel-recognised date, i.e.

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "))
```

Comment: I have tried this formula but it's returning the #VALUE error so I give the instance number which worked. This formula worked **=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," ",2))**

Comment: @AbdulHanan, the answer was based on your sample date which (both in the title and body of the question) contains only a single **,** - data that are not representative are unlikely to yield an optimal solution